Clustered column chart data labels display inconsistently in Power Bi
In Power Bi I get that my data labels don't display consistently. They are configured the same for each of the series.

According to online resources I need to set the "format" to 100% but can't find the setting being referenced in my Power Bi version (2.128.1380.0 64-bit).
The labels are configured to show "Outside end".

You need more horizontal space for the chart or smaller labels.
